# Copy paste from unix file to notepad

Tags: clipboard, putty

How can I copy content of large unix file (putty tool) to notepad?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [Copy text from PuTTY to text documents](https://superuser.com/questions/1156010/how-to-copy-long-text-from-putty-to-text-document-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

### putty log file way

One way you can log the data is, generate the log file putty under session > logging. Once you have created the log file, you would be able then to call upon the log file to get the details you need. One thing of warning, notepad can't open text files larger then 4GB, you would need to rely on another tool like notepad++ or atom, or if you have bash for windows installed, they will have the unix based tools to assist with the log file.

[image: Putty logging]

### Windows 10 Bash Way

If you have windows bash installed on windows 10, you would be able to just change your bash window to a directory of `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/` then `scp` the file down. Once its completed, it will just show up in your documents on your computer.

```
thebtm@windows10:/mnt/c/Users/thebtm/Documents$ cd /mnt/c/Users/thebtm/Documents
thebtm@windows10:/mnt/c/Users/thebtm/Documents$ scp thebtm@linux-server:~/file.txt .
thebtm@linux-server's password:
file.txt                                                100%   89KB  89.4KB/s   00:00
thebtm@windows10:/mnt/c/Users/thebtm/Documents$
```

### Others Ways

- SFTP program using the SSH Port
- if the file is small enough, mailx command may be able to assist from the server (if its installed)